# Question about the 3-transistor current mirror

Tags: current-mirror

This is a basic 3-transistor current mirror:

[image]

I see some circuits add an extra resistor from emitter of Q3 to \$V^{-}\$. Just like this:

[image]

What's the purpose of this resistor?

Comment: *What's the purpose of this resistor?* Just think about what would happen if **1)** that resistor was an open and **2)** the resistor was a short. Would that make the current mirror work ? And actually this is not a current mirror as a current mirror has an input **current** while this circuit uses an input **voltage**. And that also gives a hint why that resistor is needed.

Comment: Isn't @diverger referring to a resistor (not present in his schematic) that would connect Q1 and Q2's base junction (and Q3's emitter) to the negative supply?

Comment: Yes, you are right. And that resistor is not shown in the circuit. It's just placed between the '+' and '-', and connect the emitter of Q3 and negative supply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll draw up the schematic you are talking about:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0f2nj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Rather than just tell you the answer (I will, but allow me a moment), let's start by just laying out the nodal equation for \$V_x\$ shown in the schematic:

$$\frac{V_x}{R_2}+I_{B_1}+I_{B_2}=I_{E_3}$$

Adding \$R_2\$ makes only one difference here. There are two directions to head, in considering "why" it's added.

One direction is to focus on the impact on \$Q_3\$: (1) Increased emitter current; and, (2) reduced \$r_e=\tfrac{k T}{q I_C}\$; and, (3) The ability to set \$Q_3\$'s emitter current so that it is relatively independent of the base currents for \$Q_1\$ and \$Q_2\$.

The other direction is to focus on the impact of "current in" and "current out" of the node. I think it is this latter option that matters more here.

Imagine that there is some unmanaged capacitance sitting at \$V_x\$ (to \$V_-\$.) \$Q_3\$'s emitter can charge up this capacitance up quite actively, having access to the current through \$R_1\$ multiplied by its \$\beta_{Q3}\$. But it can only be discharged through the relatively much smaller base currents (the same current through \$R_1\$ but this time divided by \$\beta_{Q_1}\$ and \$\beta_{Q_2}\$.) This asymmetry leads to an undesirable response to higher frequency changes.

Adding \$R_2\$ provides a separate way to sink current out of the node and to help balance the ability to sink and source current at \$V_x\$.

---

This is also achieved another way that you may also encounter:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fADEp0.png)</sup>

---

None of these are high precision circuits for discrete designs. They lack careful consideration of operating temperature differences, beta mismatch, and \$V_{BE}\$ mismatch, just to name a few reasons why. A lot of good work went into designing around those issues back in the 1960's. So if you are considering building these on a protoboard, you might want to research beta compensation resistors and .. well, probably Wyatt's pretty nifty design, too. (It's interesting entirely on its own.) You can also consider getting pairs of BJTs built on a common substrate for better thermal matching (BCV61 and BCV62, for example) and, in some cases, much better beta matching as well (BCM61 and BCM62, for example.)

Comment: Any link to "Wyatt's pretty nifty design" ?

Comment: @G36 Wyatt tried to get people's attention to it on EDN: http://www.edn.com/design/other/4351571/EDN--02-15-96-Peaking-current-source-has-high-rejection

Comment: @G36 He originally named it "Cascode Peaking Current Source" and developed it as part of an RF IC project, working as a Senior Engineering Fellow at Honeywell, where he then designed ICs. He may be still working as the Chief Engineer at Exelis in Clearwater, Florida. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @G36 It's performance is astounding. The output is perfecctly flat with an input voltage between 2 V and 10 V and an input current range from about \$50~\mu\textrm{A}\$ to perhaps \$200~\mu\textrm{A}\$. And it actually uses the positive tempco of its resistors (aluminum in ICs, but metal film are close enough) to compensate the BJTs. The result is spectacular. You have to add the resistor tempco to get the right results in Spice. But once you do that? Wow!

Comment: @jonk: The figures links for that paper are all *bad*. Can you provide other links.

Comment: @diverger No. I found that link with google. And yes, I _also_ saw that the figure links are all bad. Perhaps someone can post up the article, if they have a copy. (I don't.) The other alternative is to try and write the author in Florida (if he's still kicking.)

Comment: @diverger I just sent the appropriate technical editor at EDN an email asking for a way to view the article. I'll see what happens.

Comment: @diverger He said, "I'll look into it. Perhaps the next time one of us visits our print archive… " So I'm guessing "not all that quickly."

Comment: @diverger He writes again today. Says that they've located the article and that he'll let me know when they make it available, again! I think that's good news.